# My bootstrap slider carousal is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I had used the Bootstrap's carousal to show the different courses on my website(three courses at once then 3 again) it's giving me the problem. The image of current scenario is attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUcQE.jpg)Pls solve this.

I had used the Bootstrap's carousal to show the different courses on my website(three courses at once then 3 again) it's giving me the problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverfow. Without seeing a [mre] we're not going to be able to help. Attaching images of code isn't going to help either... the code should be part of the question (using [snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if possible). Please read the [help] and [ask] section in particular - it's also worth taking the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

You can check full example for bootstrap carousel and compare your code with this example and it may helpful you to identify the problem whether it's regarding css or something else.

If you want to check carousel with 3 items you can check codepen example.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).